# Web API is not working when calling through C# or jQuery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, api, asp.net-web-api

Going crazy. The first call sets the session and the 2nd call gets the session. First 'Post' call return username and session id correctly but when I try to get the session, it returns blank with status code 200.

The same is the case with HttpClient (C#) code.

Both the call works perfectly if I try to set through browser or PostMan.

```
        $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:xxxx/xxxx/api/v1/session?username=xxxx&password=xxxx", 
        type: 'POST',            
        dataType: 'application/json',
        success: function (result) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:xxxx/xxxx/api/v1/session",
                type: 'Get',
                dataType: 'application/json',
                crossDomain: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    debugger;

                },
                error: function (result) {
                    debugger;
                }
            });
        },
        error: function (result) {
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:xxxx/xxxx/api/v1/session",
                type: 'Get',
                dataType: 'application/json',
                crossDomain: true,

                success: function (result) {
                    debugger

                },
                error: function (result) {
                    debugger;
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

The Get Request from Post Man
{"sessionId":"088BE3296B8778948F649A6B7B8C064B","userName":"user1"}

Am I missing anything?

Do note that Web-APIs are exposed by third party.

Comment: Status 200 is OK. So can you change the success of the 2nd request to another name, like "resultSession". Tell me the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, in the response for the POST request, there will be a `Set-Cookie` header.

You may need to pass the cookie in the GET request.

Comment: How come its working in POSTMan / directly through browser then? And what would be the cookie value?

Comment: @Abhishek at least when in browser, it will automatically attach cookie in the request. That's why I guess it might be cookie. You can check this using Network panel in Chrome Developer tool to see the difference between successful request and failed request.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you have used the post method and trying to pass the data in query string.

```
function DoLogin() {
        if (document.getElementById("Email").value == "" && document.getElementById("Password").value == "") {
            document.getElementById("Email").focus();
            toastr.error("Please enter email and password.");
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("Email").value == "") {
            document.getElementById("Email").focus();
            toastr.error("Please enter valid email address.");
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("Password").value == "") {
            document.getElementById("Password").focus();
            toastr.error("Please enter valid password.");
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("ButtonLogin").value = "Validating your account...";
            document.getElementById("ButtonLogin").disabled = true;
            var model = {
                Email: $('#Email').val(),
                Password: $('#Password').val()
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(model),
                url: "@Url.Action("Login", "Account", null)",
                contentType: "application/json"
            }).success(function (res) {
                var Type = res.type;
                if (Type == "error") {
                    toastr.error(res.value);
                    document.getElementById("ButtonLogin").value = "login";
                    document.getElementById("ButtonLogin").disabled = false;
                }
                else {
                    window.location.href = res.returnUrl;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tried but it throws bad request error. Ideally it should work but no luck. As I mentioned I tried with HttpClient (C#) method too.